# How to get modem mode using sed or awk from a modem output?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am not an expert in bash and I have troubles in filtering out the correct substring.

I have

```
echo "AT^SYSCFGEX=\\\"0201\\\",3fffffff,2,4,7fffffffffffffff,,"
```

that results as

```
AT^SYSCFGEX=\"0201\",3fffffff,2,4,7fffffffffffffff,,
```

How can I get `0201` as the result? I am struggling with that.

Comment: If you're not picky about using `sed` or `awk` in particular, then `grep -wo '[0-9]\{4\}'` or `grep -Ewo '[0-9]{4}'` will output a matching sequence of exactly four decimal digits that form a complete word (i.e. with word boundaries either side)

Comment: @steeldriver: That sounds like an answer. :-]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### With `sed`

```
sed -r 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1/'
```

extracts the first number from the string.

#### Example run

```
$ echo "AT^SYSCFGEX=\\\"0201\\\",3fffffff,2,4,7fffffffffffffff,," | sed -r 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1/'
0201
```

#### Explanations

- `-r` – use extended regular expressions
- `s/a/b/` – substitute `a` by `b`
- `[^0-9]*` – grab everything except a digit, here it matches `AT^SYSCFGEX=\"`
- `([0-9]+)` – grab at least one digit and save it in a group, here it matches `0201`
- `.*` – grab the whole rest of the line, here it matches `\",3fffffff,2,4,7fffffffffffffff,,`
- `\1` – get content of first group saved before

Comment: What does `-r` mean?

Comment: And what if the string has a `\n` char at the beginnig? This command doesn't filter it out for some reason. I can pipe it to `tr -d '\n'`, but why?

Comment: @Pilot6 You mean an empty line? You can delete those with `/^$/d`, or just make the whole thing `sed -nr 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1/p'` to print only lines where the expression does anything.

Comment: This probably could use `-n` or  extra pattern matching as in  `sed -nr '/SYSCFGEX/ { s/[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1/p}'`

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative using `grep` in PCRE-mode (`-P`) with regex lookarounds, showing only the matching parts of each line (`-o`):

```
grep -Po '(?<=\\")\d+(?=\\")'
```

This matches all numbers that are enclosed in backslash-escaped double quotes, like `\"0201\"`, but without returning the quotes in the result.

- `(?<=\\")` is a lookbehind, which matches an empty string if it is preceded by the inner pattern (`\"`).
- `\d+` matches one or more digits.
- `(?=\\")` is a lookahead, which matches an empty string if it is followed by the inner pattern (`\"`).

Example:

```
$ echo "AT^SYSCFGEX=\\\"0201\\\",3fffffff,2,4,7fffffffffffffff,," | grep -Po '(?<=\\")\d+(?=\\")'
0201
```

Comment: Nice! An alternative is `grep -Po '\d+' | head -1`.

Answer (score 2):

### With [`bash`’s Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal)

If you want to use just `bash` you can do it like this:

```
$ var="AT^SYSCFGEX=\\\"0201\\\",3fffffff,2,4,7fffffffffffffff,,"
$ echo ${var#*\"}
0201\",3fffffff,2,4,7fffffffffffffff,,
$ var=${var#*\"}
$ echo ${var%%\\\"*}
0201
```

#### Explanations

- `${var#*\"}` – expands to the content of variable `var` with the pattern matching `*"` (i.e. everything until `"`) stripped from the beginning
- `${var%%\\\"*}` – expands to the content of variable `var` with the pattern matching `\"*` (i.e. everything from `\"`) stripped from the end.

#### Further reading

- [Bash Hackers Wiki: Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal)
- [`man bash`/EXPANSION/Parameter Expansion](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc13)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `awk` approach. The idea here is that `awk` ( or to be precise, GNU `awk` ) can use multiple characters as separators. Thus, we can use `\` and `"` as separators, to extract the desired string with:

```
awk -F '[\\\\"]' '{print $3}'
```

Note the multiple `\` , which are necessary to escape the backslash and avoid it being interpreted by the shell as escape for the next character.

With the `echo` command in the question,

```
$ echo "AT^SYSCFGEX=\\\"0201\\\",3fffffff,2,4,7fffffffffffffff,," | awk -F '[\\\\"]' '{print $3}'
0201
```

Alternatively, we could just use `"` as separator and cut off the last `\` via `substr()` function:

```
$ echo "AT^SYSCFGEX=\\\"0201\\\",3fffffff,2,4,7fffffffffffffff,," | awk -F '"' '{print substr($2,1,length($2)-1)}'
0201
```

Comment: I tried this first, but I didn't know that `[]`was needed. Can you help with removing preceding `\n`. I get the output with new line in the beginning. I fix it with `tr -d '\n'`.

Comment: @Pilot6  That's peculiar. `awk` should treat each line as separate record, so that newline shouldn't appear there, and there's something else going on.   I understand the `echo` part is just the minimal example. What's the actual command you're piping into `awk` ?

Comment: @Pilot6 Actually, nevermind. I think I know what's the issue there. The command you're piping probably has extra line in the output, and `awk` performs the actions for each line, so it tries to print field 3  (the `$3` part) even if it's not there or empty.  You can get rid of that by adding a pattern matching to get the exact line you want, like `awk -F '[\\\\"]' '/SYSCFGEX/{print $3}'`. So this will only look for lines with `SYSCFGEX` in it. Or if you're looking for second line specifically, you can use `NR == 2` instead of  `/SYSCFGEX/`

Comment: Exatctly.` awk -F '[\\\\"]' '/SYSCFGEX/{print $2}'` this is perfect. I can do it shoreter, since there is an empty string first. Like any char in the pattern.

Comment: I am getting a command from a modem with `gcom`. It gives an extra empty line before the output. And with `sed` I still get that line. Now it is solved. Sorry that I don't accept your answer, because the first one is good too, without that detail.

Comment: @Pilot6 No big deal, if the problem is solved that's all that matters